# What are the white tubes underneath the Canopy of the F-22 Raptor?

Tags: aircraft-design, military, us-air-force, canopy

I was looking at the Raptor and noticed the white looking tubes underneath the canopy. Do the tubes have a purpose?  If so what is the purpose/function of the tubes? Are there any other aircraft with this kind function? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Speculating: this could be part of the canopy locking assembly, likely in addition to the six grey points you can see along the middle rim of the canopy.

Comment: Chemtrail storage containers

Comment: @Richard clearly its plastic downpipe from rainwater spouting, being used as air ducting so the incoming breeze is redirected at the windscreen to keep it defrosted....

Comment: "Do the tubes have a purpose?" While I'm not an airplane designer, I'd bet everything on a (modern fighter) plane has a purpose - otherwise it would be removed to reduce weight.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Those are Cartridge Actuation Devices (CADs) - pyrotechnic charges used during canopy separation for canopy jettison or ejection. Note the nozzles at the outboard ends and the ignition wires inboard.

You can see a ground test of a similar unit installed on an F-16 below.

Comment: What is that person doing there? Looks like they are holding something, a microphone or other sensor perhaps. Surely, given there are two rockets firing and in a few moments a canopy falling from the sky, they could have set up a tripod or something.

Comment: It might be the guy who pulled the cable triggering the pyrotechnic cartridges (?)

Comment: Looks like they're following the instructions on the side of most fighters, [1. Push button to open door 2. Pull ring/handle out X feet to jettison canopy.](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/30320/what-is-the-rescue-arrow-decal-on-a-military-jet-pointing-to) I feel like I'd want to tie on a longer rope and stand farther back if it's not an emergency, but maybe there's some reason they can't.

Comment: He's wearing a hard hat, and what looks like some sort of protective suit (hard to tell from this low-res image, but it looks like a fireman's coat, designed for protection in burning buildings and the like).  He's probably fine.  Probably.

Comment: @CarloFelicione from [other photos in this sequence](https://www.f-16.net/g3/f-16-photos/album03/alq), and [a video of what looks like the same test](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7VZ_GDONRD0), it's a person yanking the cord. A lot more nonchalant about the canopy flying overhead than I'd be.

Comment: @CameronSS [cool guys don't look at explosions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sqz5dbs5zmo)

Comment: @CameronSS excellent!  I’ll use that as my reference!